# Error starting Business network application in Hyperledger fabric composer-- Multi host peer environment

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm creating a fabric network with 5 peers.

2 peers, CA and orderer running on machine 1,
 1 peer and couch instance on machine 2,
 1 peer and couch instance on machine 3,
 1 peer and couch instance on machine 4.

They all are on the same channel. I was able to install the .bna into the network. But when I tried starting the application using composer tool, using the below command

**"composer network start -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -n blockv6 -V 0.0.1  -A admin -S adminpw"**

I'm getting no valid response error

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message:  is not a valid endorsement system chaincode)
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Unknown chaincodeType: NODE)
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Unknown chaincodeType: NODE)
Command failed

Below is my createPeerAdmin script's connection  profile

```
       {

            "name": "hlfv1",
            "x-type": "hlfv1",
            "x-commitTimeout": 300,
           "version": "1.0.0",
         "client": {
    "organization": "Org1",
    "connection": {
        "timeout": {
            "peer": {
                "endorser": "300",
                "eventHub": "300",
                "eventReg": "300"
            },
            "orderer": "300"
        }
    }
},
"channels": {
    "composerchannel": {
        "orderers": [
            "orderer.example.com"
        ],
        "peers": {
            "peer0.org1.example.com": {},
             "peer1.org1.example.com": {},
              "peer2.org1.example.com": {},
              "peer3.org1.example.com": {},
              "peer4.org1.example.com": {}
        }
    }
},
"organizations": {
    "Org1": {
        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
        "peers": [
            "peer0.org1.example.com",
            "peer1.org1.example.com",
            "peer2.org1.example.com",
            "peer3.org1.example.com",
            "peer4.org1.example.com"

        ],
        "certificateAuthorities": [
            "ca.org1.example.com"
        ]
    }
},
"orderers": {
    "orderer.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://${HOST}:7050"
    }
},
"peers": {
    "peer0.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://${HOST}:7051",
        "eventUrl": "grpc://${HOST}:7053"
    },
     "peer1.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://${HOST}:8051",
        "eventUrl": "grpc://${HOST}:8053"
    },
     "peer2.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://<machineIP>:9051"
    },
     "peer3.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://<machineIP>:9051"
    },
     "peer4.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://<machineIP>:9051"
    }
},
"certificateAuthorities": {
    "ca.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "http://${HOST}:7054",
        "caName": "ca.org1.example.com"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The response you have shows that 3 peers were contacted and they each had problems instantiating the chaincode. It looks like you are using composer 0.20 so to break down the errors is as follows

- Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: is not a valid endorsement system chaincode)

You get the above error if you are using a fabric 1.1 peer with composer 0.20, composer 0.20 is not compatible with a fabric 1.1 peer.

- Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Unknown chaincodeType: NODE)

You get the above error if you are using a fabric 1.0 peer. Chaincode type of NODE was introduced in fabric 1.1

So I don't know how you've managed to have such a mixture of fabric peer levels in your network, but I suggest that you check the versions of the peers you are running and ensure they are all at 1.2 if you plan to use composer 0.20. If you want to use fabric 1.1 ensure you use composer 0.19.x

The final point I see is that there are some ${HOST} definitions in your connection profile, where others you have replaced with `<machineIP>` so I assume that those ${HOST} entries hadn't been replaced in the example you posted rather than in your real connection profile.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the version of composer helped solve this issue.

```
npm install -g composer-cli@0.19
```